# In one form or class ,how much tab we can add in android development?

Tags: android, android-tabhost

In android, how much tab we can add in one form ?
for example 4 or less than  4 mostaly wecan add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using TabHost you can theoretically add as many tabs as you wish, but they will get hard to press with your finger.